# Android Studio on mac M1

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, apple-m1, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to set up Flutter with Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Beta 3) on my Macbook 13" M1 and I can't with flutter doctor I get this information:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-arm, locale de-DE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

When I try to accept the android licences I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81909

Comment: What Java version do you have? `java --version` in a terminal.

Comment: @ariefbayu this solved my problem.

Comment: @MattU every Android Studio comes with it's own JDK

Comment: @ariefbayu if you post this as an answer I can mark my question as resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81909

Specifically, this part:

```
Go to sdk manager, and download Android SDK command line tools and try again
```